# Magic The Gathering auto card for pre release cards

Tags: discussion, mtg-autocard

How should auto card be handled on cards that have been previewed for an upcoming set but are not yet in gatherer? Should the auto card be used with the knowledge that it will be broken until the set releases or should that wait until it is released?

As a side note if auto card is done on a pre release card should it be edited out until after the release?

Personally I am of the mindset that they don't need to be added to pre release cards and they don't need to be edited out if they where added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of card links in a question is to have a useful quick reference to see card text and other information that may be useful to understanding and answering the question. A broken link does not in any way serve that purpose, so it has no value in a question.

The priority should be having a working link that provides the necessary information. Many sites, including [MythicSpoiler](http://mythicspoiler.com/), [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/), and [TCGPlayer](https://www.tcgplayer.com/) provide card information for cards that have been revealed but not published. It would be better to include links to any of those than to include broken autocard links.